# Is it possible to load other applications in Instruments?

Tags: iphone, instruments

I’d like to use Instruments to peek at some third-party applications on my iPhone, is that possible? If I attach Instruments to some of the applications I develop, everything goes well. But when I try to load some other application, Instruments complain that they can’t “get task for pid XY.” Is that a security measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the iPhone telling you that the app you're trying to run won't let the debugger attach to it. Without a debugger attached you can't run Instruments.

This is an intentional security measure, withut hacking the 3rd party apps you will not be able to view them in Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Hey.
From Instruments documentation:
*For your protection, the instrument does not allow you to process any application that is not
code-signed with your provisioning profile. This includes any copy that has been downloaded from the iTunes App Store.*